# Parsing json string and json obj in same json obj in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string

there's a json obj:

```py
{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': "{"key3": ["val3"]}"}
```

how to parse json string and json obj in the same json obj

json.load() =>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
json.loads() =>
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 232 (char 231)

Comment: use `json` library

Comment: json.load and json.loads all don't work, because this json obj contains json obj in json string

Comment: Are you sure you're JSON isn't supposed to look like this? ```{'key1': 'val1','key2': "{'key3': ['val3'] }"}```

Comment: Also can you show the full code of when you get that error?

Comment: "JSON object" isn't a thing. JSON is always a string. It can be turned into a python object. Is the thing you show us a text string, a python literal, or a python object that you've printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you want to use JSON library as Himanshu suggested.

I think this will answer your questions: https://bogotobogo.com/python/python-json-dumps-loads-file-read-write.php

the json dumps method takes in an object and returns a string:

```
a = {'foo': 3}
json.dumps(a)
>>> '{"foo": 3}'
```

the json load method takes in a file-like object, reads the data from that object, and uses that string to create an object:

```
with open('file.json') as fh:
    a = json.load(fh)
```

---

For your specific JSON case I think you want it reformatted like so:

```
import json

j = {'key1': 'val1',
    'key2': "{'key3': ['val3']}"
    }

print(json.dumps(j))
>>>> {"key1": "val1", "key2": "{'key3': ['val3']}"}
```

---

There are four methods in the json libary: load, loads, dumps, dumps. Here is what they do:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you write this using poster's example?

Comment: Added a bit to that and this should explain it, OP's example was incorrectly formatted.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to format the dict with multi-line string, then use json.dumps:

```
d = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': """{"key3": ["val3"]}"""}
json.dumps(d) # a new json string
json.loads(d["key2"]) # the obj
```